# Как получить data uri из прямой ссылки на картинку через js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, изображения, base64, uri

Собственно есть прямая ссылка на изображение: https://c.my.com/c/5

Нужно получить такое: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAyADIAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgI(и так далее)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Через `canvas`. Пример с [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript).

```js
function getBase64Image(img) {
    // Создаем пустой canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Копируем изображение в контекст canvas'a
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Получаем data-URL изображения
    return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    //return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function(){
 console.log(getBase64Image(this));
}

img.crossOrigin="anonymous"
img.src ='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4d9fe3279fd775b4f12a5cdc182fa941?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=1';
```

Comment: Мне нужно из функции возвращать результат, а потом вызывать эту функцию. Сможете подправить ?

Comment: Из какой из функции?

Comment: Из итоговой, то есть функции которая будет мне возвращать data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A...

Comment: Вы хотите вначале получить результат, а потом вызвать функцию, что за бред?

Comment: Ладно, не буду вас утруждать, спасибо